# @Binding causing memory issue in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using @@Binding which i am passing to function but it causes memory leak and app freezes.

```
import SwiftUI

struct BottomView: View {

    var accessibilityID: String
    var viewModel: ViewModel
    @Binding var selectedPoductDetails: [String: SelectedProductDetail]

    init(accessibiltyID: String, viewModel: ViewModel selectedPoductDetails: Binding<[String: SelectedProductDetail]>) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        self.accessibilityID = accessibiltyID
        self._selectedPoductDetails = selectedPoductDetails
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                let totalAmount = viewModel.totalAmount(selectedPoductDetails: 
                   selectedPoductDetails)
                Text(totalAmount)
            }
       }
    }
```

My function in another class is

```
func totalAmount(selectedPoductDetails: [String: SelectedProductDetail]) -> String {
    self.selectedProductDetails = selectedPoductDetails
    let amount = selectedPoductDetails.reduce(into: 0, { $0 += $1.value.amount })
    return amount
}
```

Why memory leak and app freeze? i am comment code

```
let totalAmount = viewModel.totalAmount(selectedPoductDetails: 
                       selectedPoductDetails)
```

everything works fine.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You just cycles calls, because assigning property activates binding, which activates update, which calls calculable body, which calls `viewModel.totalAmount` again... and go on...

just remove

```
func totalAmount(selectedPoductDetails: [String: SelectedProductDetail]) -> String {

//    self.selectedProductDetails = selectedPoductDetails       // << this !!

    let amount = selectedPoductDetails.reduce(into: 0, { $0 += $1.value.amount })
    return amount
}
```